# Where can i find the tensorflow folder which i pulled from DockerHub? (on windows7)

Tags: docker, path, directory, tensorflow

I wanted to pull the latest updations of the tensorflow repo on github, but in order to do that i first have to find the image i pulled from DockerHub on my drive.

Can anyone tell where to find the tensorflow directory??

I have tried searching everywhere but really can't find it. I really need it for my practical implementation of small machine learning projects i've been thinking. Any help will be appreciated.!

Comment: To clarify: are you asking us to tell you where you put this image?

Comment: The actual files you pulled from docker are not very useful to you.
You download "images" from dockerhub, which you can view by running "docker images" from your terminal.

Comment: @JoeC please check the following link; you guys <https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#2> and check out the last section on the page of "Retrieving the training code".

Comment: I gained access to the folder on the docker CMD line and have git pulled it, but can't physically access it on the Windows explorer.